# How to get notification when any process(.exe) ex. notepad exits in C#?

Tags: c#, process

How to get notification when any process(.exe) ex. notepad is closed in C#?

Comment: Please could you explain your problem more....

Comment: Actually I want to keep record of all applications opened in a day with time spend on  it. For that i want notification when application closed.Is there any way to do it or else?

Answer (score 9):

The simplest way is to create a `System.Diagnostics.Process` for the Notepad process you want to monitor:

```
  Process p = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad.exe").First();
  p.Exited += (sender, args) => Debug.WriteLine("Process has exited!");
```

Theoretically, you can do this for all running processes (with `Process.GetProcesses()`), but this won't give you the ability to be notified for any FUTURE processes, just the ones running when you start the monitoring.

A more low-level solution that could give you information on any process/window being closed is using CBT Hooks, with a .NET wrapper supplied [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188966.aspx#S3), but this requires a lot more manual management, since it gives you information on closing Win32 window, not only processes.